# UIScrollView Problems on iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I am trying to get a `UIScrollView` on an iPad to work. I have looked at nearly all existing questions but none have really solved my problem. So basically here is my code upfront:

```
[scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, 2320);
```

Called in `viewDidLoad` by the way. When I build and run, the scroll views side bar changes its position when I scroll (indicating that it is working) but the view does not change/remains at the top. My view consists of many `UIImageView`'s, but I do not think that is a problem. Also for my arrangement, my scroll view is at the front of the whole view.

Thank you!

UPDATE:

So basically what is happening is my `UIView`'s scroll view does not cover the WHOLE view. It does not cover the most top part where I have a label and a button. But however, when I load it to the iPad, my images are covering the top.... making it now possible to scroll up and down.

Why is this happening?

Screenshot:

[image: On Simulator]

UPDATED:

My code:

```
[scroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, 1500);

[scroll addSubview: i1];
[scroll addSubview: i2];
[scroll addSubview: i3];
[scroll addSubview: i4];
[scroll addSubview: i5];
[scroll addSubview: i6];
[scroll addSubview: i7];
[scroll addSubview: i8];
[scroll addSubview: line];
```

Any idea as to why this is happening?

Is adding a subview to the scroll view even correct?

UPDATE:

I have another problem, I have implemented the `touchesBegan` method and if the user touches any of those images, a pop up containing certain information is shown. That code is pretty standard though, don't need to show it. So, is there a way for a scroll view to respond to touches for its content?

The problem is that whenever I touch the image, `touchesBegan` is never called because the scroll view is in front, right? But if I send the scroll view backward scrolling does not work.

I have many problems here as you can see, but instead of looking at my code and trying to solve each mistake. I had a better idea. Here is what I am trying to do:

Have a scroll view on an iPad which scrolls through a timeline which is technically multiple images. These images are touchable. And the scroll view only takes a portion of the screen, the top part is a back button and label which should not scroll. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you sure you are adding the image views as subviews of the scrollview, not the main parent view?

Comment: No they are subviews of the main parent view, so there is obviously something I am missing out here. Should I call [scroll addSubview: image];

Comment: Yes, you should add them to the scrollview. The scrollview only scrolls its own content. If the views are added to the parent, the scrollview has no idea they even exist.

Comment: Ok I tried this, I have updated my question with some problems I have

Comment: Can we have a look at the view controller code?

Comment: all i1-8 and line is userInterAction false and scrollView is userInteraAction true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you set the frames for your subviews properly. If not, your subview will most likely default to a (0,0) position in the scrollview.

Comment: My frames? I do not modify them but they are set in the xib file

Comment: If you are setting your imageviews in the xib file, why are you adding it using addSubview in your scrollview?

Comment: you should add them to the scrollview. The scrollview only scrolls its own content. If the views are added to the parent, the scrollview has no idea they even exist.

Comment: Here's what I would do to debug: After I add the subviews to the scrollview, I will check the frame values for every subview that I've added to the scrollview to check whether they are at the position that I want. If not, then I will adjust the frames of the subviews accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you double check that the IBOutlet is actually connected?. I suggest you add an assert to make sure the ScrollView reference is initialized. That usually saves you a lot of time.

Comment: Second idea. Please, check if all of the superviews have the 'user interaction' flag set to true.

Comment: Mmmmm now that i see your updated question... your UIImageView's are subviews to the ScrollView... right?.